# Yii serve do nothing when I try to run it. (fsockopen(): unable to connect)

Tags: php, yii, yii2, fsockopen

I was trying to get started with Yii2 framework. As described in [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) i did

```
$composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
$composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic yii2-test
```

then I `cd yii2-test` and run `php yii serve --port=8888`

I expected that it would run server but it exit with code 255. Debugger said that it stops [on the line](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/console/controllers/ServeController.php#L116)

```
$fp = @fsockopen($hostname, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3);
```

and error message is

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:8888 (Connection refused)
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Some enviroment:**

Description:    Ubuntu 15.10

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: What Operating System do you running? Provide some information please. Are you sure the built-in php Webserver is running? On which port? If not, start with php -S localhost:8888

Comment: I edited my question: Ubuntu 15.10 with php 5.6.11. I don't think built-in php  webserver should be running, otherwise if I run `php yii serve --port=8888` I get an error `http://localhost:8888 is taken by another process.`. Also port number doesn't metter, I checked it is free and tried another different random ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strange behaviour was caused by xdebug setting

```
xdebug.halt_level=E_NOTICE|E_WARNING|E_USER_WARNING|E_USER_NOTICE
```

To solve my problem I had to just exclude `E_WARNING` from it.

#### Explanation

Before starting `yii serve` command checks if another application uses selected port.
This is done in method `isAddressTaken` by trying to open socket to localhost at this port

```
$fp = @fsockopen($hostname, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3);
```

, so every time the port is empty (and yii may use it), fsockopen generates warning which is suppressed by `@`.

The result: if you have xdebug and it makes all scripts to halt on warnings - `yii serve` will not start.